# Integrate vera++ (or other coding-convention tool) with Qt/QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style, qt-creator, vera++

We are developing a application with Qt and in the server we have genkin server for auto build and auto tests.
We want to have a Coding-Convention Test tool like vera++. We have no experience in vera++ or other tools but all we want is to make vera++ process every files of the Qt project (.pro). Also, is it possible to integrate this tool in QtCreator?

I couldn't find anything in Internet.
Thanks.

Comment: I found this https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Screenshots and this on internet http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60008-Include-vera-in-qmake-build-process

Comment: The first link is just a screenshot. It doesn't tell how to integrate. And the second is useless too!

Comment: Actually, first link with screenshot answers on your question "Also, is it possible to integrate this tool in QtCreator?". If second link useless, then, I think, you'll should write some scripts to invoke vera++ tool on your source base.

Comment: First link answers that this tool is possible to integrate in QtCreator but doesn't tell how to integrate!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

I have integrated vera++ in a composite qmake project by adding the following lines in the file `.qmake.conf` in the root directory of the project:

```
defineReplace(absolute_paths) {
    result =
    for(path, ARGS) {
        result += $$absolute_path($$path, $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_)
    }
    return($$result)
}
equals(TEMPLATE, subdirs): prepareRecursiveTarget(vera++)
else {
    # We prefix the report file name with the project file base name to prevent name collisions.
    VERA_TARGET = $$basename(_PRO_FILE_).vera++.xml
    vera++.commands = vera++ --checkstyle-report $$VERA_TARGET --show-rule $$absolute_paths($$HEADERS) $$absolute_paths($$SOURCES)
    QMAKE_CLEAN += $$VERA_TARGET
}
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += vera++
```

This adds a recursive make target `vera++` that processes all the header and source files in each of the non-subdirs sub-projects.

To generate the XML reports, call the following commands:

```
qmake
make qmake_all
make vera++
```

#### Additional information

`.qmake.conf` is automatically included in all the .pro files in all subdirectories.

- qmake

  - [defineReplace()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replace-functions)
  - [prepareRecursiveTarget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#preparerecursivetarget-target)
- [vera++](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Running)

Comment: Note that a collection of vera++ reports generated this way can be processed by [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) with the [SonarQube C++ Community Plugin](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx) using the following rule: `sonar.cxx.vera.reportPath=**/*.vera++.xml`